# hamcrest: how to match array is subset of another array?

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest

Given that:

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4};
int[] b = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

**How to asser that "a" is a subset of "b" using hamcrest matchers?**

The following works

```
assertThat(Arrays.asList(b), hasItems(a));
```

But since I am creating "a" from "b", I would prefer to apply the asserts on "a" as the value.
Something like

```
assertThat(a, isSubsetOf(b));
```

Additionally it is preferable to avoid converting the array to a list.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use a combination of the [`Every`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/2.2/org/hamcrest/core/Every.html) and [`IsIn`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/2.2/org/hamcrest/collection/IsIn.html) matcher:

```
assertThat(Arrays.asList(a), everyItem(in(b)));
```

This does check if every item of `a` is contained in `b`. Make sure `a` and `b` are of type `Integer[]` otherwise you might get unexpected results.

If you are using an older version of hamcrest (for example 1.3) you can use the following:

```
assertThat(Arrays.asList(a), everyItem(isIn(b)));
```

In the latest version [`isIn` is deprecated in favor of `in`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/2.2/org/hamcrest/collection/IsIn.html).

Comment: The above is a great find. The only issue would be if duplicates need to be supported. If `a` contains two `3` values but `b` only contains one, the above would give a false positive.

Comment: @JohnB I got the impression that the OP doesn't care about those duplicates because of the suggestion to use `assertThat(Arrays.asList(b), hasItems(a))` which doesn't handle this case either. But you are absolutely right if you do care you have to write your own more sophisticated matcher like @kmmanu suggested.

Comment: This works for me. The important thing is to check if its a subset.For now i will ignore the duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

Create your own custom matcher by extending `org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher` and use it in the `assertThat()` method.  You can refer the code of `org.hamcrest.collection.IsArrayContaining`  and create your own matcher

Comment: yeah, if there is isn't a option already available with hamcrest.

Answer (score 1):

If [assertj](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/) is an option for you:

```
    assertThat(b).contains(a); // order doesn't matter
    assertThat(b).containsSequence(a); // order matters
```